# How to download files from selected folder of Google Drive replacing existing on Heroku?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I have files located on Google Drive (link "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CuiRmfX2ORIzb62EM-L1x6UCm6t2uu4M?usp=sharing").
This file will be updated every day without code, just removing it from google drive and uploading a new one.
I need code to do following things.

- Log into this link or just google drive
- Download all the files from csv folder (which is inside of different folder like drive/salescontrol7/csv) to folder 'project_csv' which is for now my python directory but will be deployed to heroku.
- Save downloaded files by replacing old ones in the current directory (it means if movies_metadata exists it should replace it not save as movies_matadata(1)).

I need the simplest way, so I'm using PyDrive .

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive


gauth = GoogleAuth()


gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")

if gauth.credentials is None:
    gauth.GetFlow()
    gauth.flow.params.update({'access_type': 'offline'})
    gauth.flow.params.update({'approval_prompt': 'force'})

    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()

elif gauth.access_token_expired:

    gauth.Refresh()
else:


    gauth.Authorize()

gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file1 in file_list:
  print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))
```

But all I was able to do get list of folders and files on my-drive.
How can access to folder salescontrol7/csv and then download everything from there replacing files in project folder if there are?

Also maybe there is a way to do this without PyDrive just using publically shared link?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution using gdown instead (https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown).
It does download files from public link, and replaces folder each time.

```
# a folder
url = "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15uNXeRBIhVvZJIhL4yTw4IsStMhUaaxl"
gdown.download_folder(url, quiet=True, use_cookies=False)

# same as the above, but with the folder ID
id = "15uNXeRBIhVvZJIhL4yTw4IsStMhUaaxl"
gdown.download_folder(id=id, quiet=True, use_cookies=False)
```

These two lines can help with that!